# Why did Furious 7 get an 'A' certificate in India but got a 'PG-13' certificate in USA?

Tags: content-rating, fast-and-furious-franchise, furious-7

In India, U/A stands for Unrestricted Public Exhibition with parental guidance for children below 12 years. This rating is given to a movie which contains mild violence, language and sexuality. But **Furious 7** got A : Adults: which stands for for Adult audience above 18 years only. This rating is given to a movie which contains heavy doses of violence, sexuality, frightening images and language.

Why did Furious 7 get an 'A' certificate in India but got a 'PG-13' certificate in USA?

Comment: Easy answer - public morals perceptions are different, and enforced to the standards of those countries' regulations.

Comment: It might got Adult rating because of some swear words etc.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Low necklines, cleavages and parties are enough to get an A rating here -_-

Comment: The answer to every "why did movie X get a rating of Y in the US" question is the same: because a secret group of people who make this decision decided it be that way.

Answer (score 4):

The rating system in the U.S. is very opaque. The raters' identities are kept secret and their decisions cannot be formally appealed. You should watch the documentary *[This Film Is Not Yet Rated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Film_Is_Not_Yet_Rated)*.

A movie's rating may also be the result of some extended negotiation between the studio and the MPAA. Filmmakers will often shoot scenes that can later be cut in order to get a R or PG-13 rating.

In short, there are factors beyond simple moral standards that dictate the rating a movie receives.

Comment: While this is **true** it doesn't answer the OP's question, which is more about the **Indian** certificate than about the US rating. If you read the comments on the question, you'll see that India doesn't have a PG-13 equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I read the quotation as more focused on the US rating system.  My bad.

Comment: @Catija There is U/A. My fault to create that confusion

Answer (score 1):

Censorship rules are different in different countries. In India, the dialogues containing the word "Fuck" is censored! 
Likewise, it gets an 'A' for some of the reasons which @AnkitSharma has put in comment( Low necklines, cleavages or even showing blood in the screen)

Answer (score 1):

Indian censorship is quite strict in comparison to US censorship. What is acceptable by [MPAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America) for might not be for [CBFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Board_of_Film_Certification).

If we realty draw a equivalent of PG-13 of MPAA with CBFC then we will get U/A or UA.

Form [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Board_of_Film_Certification#Certificates):

> **U/A** (Parental Guidance for children below the age of 12 years)
>
> Films with the U/A certification can contain moderate adult themes,
>   that are not strong in nature and can be watched by a child under
>   parental guidance. These films can contain some strong violence,
>   moderate sex (without any traces of nudity or sexual detail),
>   frightening scenes and muted abusive and filthy language.

Now we can debate whether the violence and filthy language of Furious 7 fit under this definition  of not but as per CBFC it doesn't. As Spectre needed [cut scenes to qualify for U/A certificate](http://mashable.com/2015/11/18/james-bond-spectre-censored-india/#IOEWMzdEzuqL). This James Bond film incident also became part of famous meme and twitter trends called [#SanskariJamesBond](https://twitter.com/hashtag/SanskariJamesBond?src=hash&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw).

So in short, different country different rating system.